# Connecting to an Access DB via SharePoint ASP.Net GridView

Tags: asp.net, database, sharepoint, ms-access, active-directory

I have an ASP.Net GridView control on an ASPX page hosted on a SharePoint site. I got our IT group to add the read/write permissions for SharePoint server/services Active Directory group  to the network drive where the Access MDB file is hosted. When I run the page, it still says the server doesn't have permission to read the database. (I know for a fact the DB is not opened exclusively). What am I doing wrong?

Here is my GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<asp:boundfield DataField="last_name" HeaderText="last_name" SortExpression="last_name">
</asp:boundfield>
<asp:boundfield DataField="first_name" HeaderText="first_name" SortExpression="first_name">
</asp:boundfield>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb" ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\SERVER\sb30$\AccessBase\accessbase.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [last_name], [first_name] FROM [BDONAMES]">
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

Comment: Are you sure it's not using an account on the IIS site for an aspx page instead of SharePoint?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your question, but it's definitely SharePoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been researching this and not sure about asp.net but sharepoint will not connect to a .mdb file because of security.  it will connect to the new 2010 version of an access file (forgot the extension)

Comment: Thanks Patty, can you provide some links to where you found that SharePoint will not connect to MDB? I won't stop pursuing this goal unless it's proven to be impossible. ASP.Net can definitely connect to an MDB as I've done it. It would be a little ridiculous if it were impossible, security is good, but the ability to change the settings is crucial and I'd be shocked if there's nothing I can do. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: According to this article, SharePoint blocks MDB. http://databases.about.com/od/access/a/accdb.htm

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user also has create rights in the directory where the MDB is so it can create its locking (LDB) file.

Comment: Yeah it looks like everything is enabled, full control. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are all the other users out? You can test this my trying to rename the MDB and see if you are getting locked out.

Comment: Nobody is using the DB but why would they need to be out of it? Access Database driver allows for simultaneous connections right

Comment: Yes, but if someone logs into it and doesn't have rights to write the locking file it may lock the entire database exclusively.